# Make an array out of scripts in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to call on random audio files depending on which script I call (Tonic Function, Dominant Function, Predominant Function in pic), but to do this I'm trying to make an array in my original script (Elements) of these three scripts. How can I do this?

Related parts of code:

```
// Different Textures
public Sprite[] emptyTextures;
public Sprite mineTexture;
//public AudioClip[] audioFiles;
public Script[] chanceAudio; // this is the problem

// further down
else
GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = emptyTextures[adjacentCount];
GetComponent<Script>().script = chanceAudio[adjacentCount]; // this is the problem
//GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = audioFiles[adjacentCount]; // do I need this?
//GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play(); // do I need this?
```

Beginner at C# so any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I'm still confused with your Question Can you explain it in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

There is no class `Script`, so you won't be able to do it this way. Think about what your three scripts have in common: At the very least, they all derive from `MonoBehaviour`. So you could do:

```
public MonoBehaviour[] chanceAudio;
```

Unity can serialize this and you will be able to drag and drop your scripts into the array. However, you will only gain access to all the public fields, properties and functions of `MonoBehaviour`. What I suspect you want to do, is gain access to some common field or function of your three scripts.
You could achieve that by writing an (abstract) base class (or interface) for `Tonic function`, `Dominant Function`and `Predominant Function` that contains their shared properties and functions. So you would write something like:

```
public abstract class MusicalFunction : MonoBehaviour
{
    // YOU CODE HERE
}
```

Then update your scripts: `public class DominantFunction : MusicalFunction` etc.
Finally, in `Element`:

```
public MusicalFunction[] chanceAudio;
```

Now you will be able to access everything declared `public` inside `MusicalFunction`.
Hope this helps you out.